# Retrieve records against most recent state/attribute value

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, amazon-redshift

Having a de-normalized structure in Redshift and plan is to keep creating records and while retrieving only consider most recent attributes against users.

Following is the table:

```
user_id   state  created_at
1         A      15-10-2015 02:00:00 AM
2         A      15-10-2015 02:00:01 AM
3         A      15-10-2015 02:00:02 AM
1         B      15-10-2015 02:00:03 AM
4         A      15-10-2015 02:00:04 AM
5         B      15-10-2015 02:00:05 AM
```

And required result set is:

```
user_id   state  created_at
2         A      15-10-2015 02:00:01 AM
3         A      15-10-2015 02:00:02 AM
4         A      15-10-2015 02:00:04 AM
```

I have the query which retrieve the said result:

```
select user_id, first_value AS state
from (
   select user_id, first_value(state) OVER (
                     PARTITION BY user_id
                     ORDER BY created_at desc
                     ROWS between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW)
   from customer_properties
   order by created_at) t
where first_value = 'A'
```

Is this the best way to retrieve or can the query be improved?

Comment: created_at column is getting used in the query and was missing in the sample data, question has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best query depends on various details: selectivity of the query predicate, cardinalities, data distribution. If `state = 'A'` is a selective condition (view rows qualify), this query should be substantially faster:

```
SELECT c.user_id, c.state
FROM   customer_properties c
LEFT   JOIN customer_properties c1 ON c1.user_id = c.user_id
                                  AND c1.created_at > c.created_at
WHERE  c.state = 'A'
AND    c1.user_id IS NULL;
```

*Provided*, there is an index on `(state)` (or even `(state, user_id, created_at)`) and another one on `(user_id, created_at)`.

There are various ways to make sure a later version of the row does not exist:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

If `'A'` is a common value in `state`, this more generic query will be faster:

```
SELECT user_id, state
FROM (
   SELECT user_id, state
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS rn
   FROM   customer_properties
   ) t
WHERE  t.rn = 1
AND    t.state = 'A';
```

I removed `NULLS LAST`, assuming that `created_at` is defined `NOT NULL`. Also, I don't think Redshift has it:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Both queries should work with the limited functionality of Redshift. With modern Postgres, there are better options:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Your original would return *all* rows per `user_id`, if the latest row matches. You would have to fold duplicates, needless work ...